# How to replace long string in a specific columns for it's all rows with sub string containing in a column.row

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if there's any thing is not clear enough 
First of all I have exported an outlook email data to a csv file
this CSV file contains columns called subject,from,to..... etc
all I need now I want to replace the values in every row in this column Subject with a Sub String which contains in value in this rows' column 
for example:
I have a row in subject and filled with data like:

```
LDELE44328 SSV report_R4_42313 (Delta)
LDELM44358 ....................etc
LDELS44258 ....................etc

LSINE44328 SSV report_R4_42313 (Delta)
LSINI44328 ....................etc
LSINS44328 ....................etc

LCAIS12345 ....................etc
LCAIN12345.....................etc
```

We noticed that the String I want to change consists 5 Chars and 5 numbers

It is my simplest code I want use like

```
 data2 = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\mwx707566\Desktop\test.CSV', usecols= 
 ['Subject','Body', 'From: (Name)', 'To: (Name)' ])
 pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
 data2.columns = data2.columns.str.replace(' ','')
 data2['x'] = data2['Subject'].str.extract(pat='^L(DEL|SIN|CAI)')
 data2['x'] = data2['Subject'].str[1:4]
 print(data2)
 data2.Subject
```

data2.Subject output:

```
 0           LDELE44328 SSV report_R4_42313 (Delta)
 1                SSV Progress Tracker @ 6 May-2019
 2                SSV Progress Tracker @ 6 May-2019
 3                SSV Progress Tracker @ 5 May-2019
 4                SSV Progress Tracker @ 5 May-2019
 5        RE: LDELE14029 SSV report_R3_42312(Delta)
 6        RE: LDELE14029 SSV report_R3_42312(Delta)
 7        RE: LDELW14978 SSV report_R3_42322(Delta)
 8        RE: LDELW14978 SSV report_R3_42322(Delta)
 9       RE: LDELE34167 SSV report_R3_42252 (Delta)
 10          LDELE54006 SSV report_R3_42202 (Delta)
 11    LCAIN10111 SSV Report_R1_41091 ( New Cairo )
 12    LCAIN10111 SSV Report_R1_41091 ( New Cairo )
 13    LCAIN10111 SSV Report_R1_41091 ( New Cairo )
```

I want the out put like this:

```
  0           LDELE44328
  5        LDELE14029
  6        LDELE14029
  7        LDELW14978
  8        LDELW14978
  9       LDELE34167
```

We noticed that there's a three statics sub string which contains 3 static SUB String CAI,SIN,DEL

So how can I create a method like this case I want to replace all these rows to those sub strings in the same rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.extract`:

```
x = df['col'].str.extract(pat='(L(?:DEL|CAI|SIN).\d{5})').dropna()

print(x)
```

Output:

```
             0
0   LDELE44328
5   LDELE14029
6   LDELE14029
7   LDELW14978
8   LDELW14978
9   LDELE34167
10  LDELE54006
11  LCAIN10111
12  LCAIN10111
13  LCAIN10111
```

Comment: thanks for your answer now after I use the extract I want to replace the row value with the extracted data like
LDELE44328 SSV report_R4_42313 (Delta)  DEL change to >>>>>> LDELE44328 @Perl

Comment: please check my edit one I didn't reach what I need exactly

Comment: Just extract the first 10 characters with `df['x'] = df['col'].str[0:10]`?